# SharePoint 2013 CSOM where is Folder.MoveTo?

Tags: 2013, document-library, folder, csom, move

I have to implement a functionality of moving a document folder and was hoping to use [Folder.MoveTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.moveto.aspx); But I don't see it in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime for the [Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.aspx) class.

**Note -** I am working on SP 2013 Foundation
[image]

**Build Error:**
Error   2   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder' does not contain a definition for 'MoveTo' and no extension method 'MoveTo' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Code:**

```
   private static void FolderMove(ClientContext clientContext, Guid listId, string folderUrl
        , string destinationFolderUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(listId);
            clientContext.Load(list, w => w.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, w => w.ParentWeb.Url);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Folder folder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
            clientContext.Load(folder);
            var destinationFolder = folder.MoveTo(destinationFolderUrl);

            clientContext.Load(destinationFolder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using SP2013 or 2010 . Folder.MoveTo is only available in 2013 version.

Comment: Working on SP2013 Foundation

Comment: Just to troubleshoot check whether , the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll file referenced is from the 15 hive , ie 2013 version and not the 2010 one

Comment: Yes I did confirm that, please refer the updated question.

Comment: Are you getting build error or error while running?

Comment: I am cannot find the MoveTo method for folder all together. Please see the updated question with build error.

Comment: If you haven't found the answer to this, you have to use the PnP library. You can add a nuget package called SharePoint PnP Core (or Online).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have seen this reply already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320394/1648371

It's actually saying that there is no MoveTo method for folders, but you have to create a new folder, move all the content, and then delete the old folder.
If you are interested in only renaming a folder and not in the content you can use something like

```
folder.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, newFolderUrl);
```